# how to change item Label in p:selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a `p:selectOneMenu` with the `itemValue` as true/false (**boolean**) but i want to display Yes/No instead of true/false.

```
<p:selectOneListbox value="#{tstMB.value}" converter="#{tstConverter}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue=""/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{tstMB.valueLst}"  var="tst" 
                              itemLabel="#{tst.status}" itemValue="#{tst}"/>
</p:selectOneListbox>
```

in the above code `tst.status` returns true/false, but i want to display somethings like Yes/No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe change from:

```
itemLabel="#{tst.status}"
```

to:

```
itemLabel="#{tst.status ? 'Yes' : 'No'}"
```

will help.

Of corse, if your application is localized use some localized strings in place of these string constants.

Answer (score 0):

Write another method in the class which is the type of `tst`, let's say `getDisplayStatus` in which you return Yes/No instead of true/false.
Then you replace `itemLabel="#{tst.status}"` with `itemLabel="#{tst.displayStatus}"`